# S0602 - whether to report Quantity (C0130) or Par Amount (C0140) for Money Market Funds?

Tags: solvency-ii

We have several positions in a money market [fund](https://www.fundsquare.net/security/documents?idInstr=230565) ([CIC](http://rawfocus.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/eiopa-cic-codes.html) IE43) to report in the S.06.02 QRT, and we receive source data for both Quantity & Par Amount.  These are actually identical.

Which one should be used, given that - per [definitions](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32015R2450) below - we should use one or the other?  Is Par amount 'relevant' in this case?

**C0130 Quantity**

> Number of assets, for relevant assets. This item shall not be reported
>   if item Par amount (C0140) is reported.

**C0140 Par amount**

> Amount outstanding measured at par amount, for all assets where this
>   item is relevant, and at nominal amount for CIC = 72, 73, 74, 75 and
>   79 if applicable. This item shall not be reported if item Quantity
>   (C0130) is reported.